# A single SQL query to list the names of all students who are enrolled and are doing a module

Tags: sql, oracle10g

List the names of all students who are enrolled on the Computer Science and are doing the Database module.

Here are my tables:

[image]

Comment: This looks like homework ... what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: What have you already tried to make this work?  It helps if you show your existing query so that we are able to highlight any errors you might be having.

Comment: seriosly. SO is not a place for doing others homework ;-)

Comment: Please find a better title.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: This question shows no effort at all; it's a simple set of images ( neither the effort to post usable sample data), the title contains something that has nothing to do with the content of the question. I can't really understand why the only vote is an upvote....

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

`SELECT c.Stud_name,a.Module_Name,b.Prog_Name FROM Module a
INNER JOIN Programme b ON a.Dept_id = b.Dept_id
INNER JOIN Student c ON b.Stud_id = c.Stud_id
WHERE a.Module_Name = 'Database' OR Module_ID = 013`

If you are not familliar with joins. Try to understand it. I filter it wih module name or module id. you can choose either one.